# How to secure communication even further between server and Apple notification servers?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

I have a server running by Amazon, who has notification capabilities for the user (push notifications). I have the code all working and have no question about that. To make the push working I have to open the outbound port 2195.

The problem is that I have the destination set to 0.0.0.0/0 (everywhere) to make it work.

Is there anyway in the security groups of Amazon or in Linux itself (I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) to restrict the destination even further?

Comment: Sure, you'd need to have a network list for the push notification service you're using, then limit outbound connections to that list.

Comment: Ask Apple for the IP ranges they use for their notification servers.

Comment: @AndréB. I did that, but they are not willing to give it that easily and say it should not be that big of a deal.

Comment: @user3892683 I believe Apple has their own IP range (search for it), so you can at least only allow outbound connections to that. Still not as good as only allowing the notification servers, but better than nothing.

Comment: I find this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688852/ip-address-ranges-for-apns-servers  and the documentation still is the same. So can I trust on arrowing it down to 17.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple support document #HT203609: Unable to use Apple Push Notification service (APNs)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609)

> The APNs servers use load balancing. Your devices will not always connect to the same public IP address for notifications. The entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so it's best to allow this range in your firewall settings.

[Developer tech note #tn2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG41) says pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I find that out yesterday too (see my comment), but thanks anyway.